# Can we extract texts between tables in PDF using Tabula in Java?

Tags: java, tabula

I was able to extract the tables using Tabula. I looked for ways on how to output the texts in between them using Tabula but it seems like it is only for tables. Any idea on how to do it?

```
public static List<Table> extractTablesFromPDF(PDDocument document) {
    NurminenDetectionAlgorithm detectionAlgorithm = new NurminenDetectionAlgorithm();

    ExtractionAlgorithm algExtractor;

    SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm extractor=new SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm();

    ObjectExtractor extractor = new ObjectExtractor(document);
    PageIterator pages = extractor.extract();
    List<Table> tables=new ArrayList<Table>(); 
    while (pages.hasNext()) {
        Page page = pages.next();
        if (extractor.isTabular(page)) {
            algExtractor=new SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm();
        }
        else
            algExtractor=new BasicExtractionAlgorithm(); 

        List<Rectangle> tablesOnPage = detectionAlgorithm.detect(page);


        for (Rectangle guessRect : tablesOnPage) {
            Page guess = page.getArea(guessRect);
            tables.addAll((List<Table>) algExtractor.extract(guess));     
        }

    }

    return tables; 
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: NO. that's not the Tabula objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maintainer of Tabula here.

There are no public methods in Tabula to do so, but you can resort to PDFBox's `PDFTextStripper`.

Looking at one of the command line tools included with PDFBox might be useful: https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/ExtractText.java